# VS Item Template NuGet package

Tags: nuget, itemtemplate, nuget-package

I am not finding any information regarding NuGet packaging for VS Item Templates. I was hoping to use a local NuGet service as a repository for Item Templates for internal projects. Does anyone have any knowledge on this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking for a similar feature and found [this](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1324)
Looks like the feature request for installing visual studio extensions was rejected, pointing to this [package](http://nuget.org/packages/VsixCommands) which might help you.